# VBA Data Sorting

Tags: excel, sorting, copy-paste, vba

[image: sheet1]
[image: sheet2]

**The problem i run into is that sometimes entire headers and data values are missing in the dataset and therefore using the last row in the script the data is shifted up by one.** For example, if i removed H11:H12 completely on sheet1 then the values for the H column associated with the data set in A11:K11 will actually be from the data set A13:K13 (or cell value H14).

**The spaces shown in the second image would not be present if the respective header is not present.**

**Question:** Given the following code; Do you think it is possible to match the data to headers and use the original offset row number alongside the column that it is matched to on sheet 2 and paste the values there? Instead the current code (and only method that worked was to find the last row).

**Examples/Thoughts:**
I'm thinking that the script will have to take a cell (such as D9 and recognizes it is a D and offsets to select D10 and matches that D9 record to sheet 2 column D and pastes the D10 data in D10 rather than D5.

second example, Script takes I17 and recognizes it matches I to sheet 2 column I and then offsets to select/copy and pastes the I19 data in I18 rather than I9.

```
Sub main()
    Dim hedaerCell As Range
    Dim labelsArray As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") '<--| reference your "headers" worksheet
        For Each hedaerCell In .Range("A1:K1") '<--| loop through all "headers"
            labelsArray = GetValues(hedaerCell.Value) '<--| fill array with all labels found under current "header"
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, hedaerCell.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(labelsArray)).Value = Application.Transpose(labelsArray)
            Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetValues(header As String) As Variant
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim iFound As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange '<--| reference your "data" worksheet
        ReDim labelsArray(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, header)) As Variant '<--| size an array to store as many "labels" as passed 'header' occurrences
        Set f = .Find(what:=header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| start seraching for passed 'header'
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = f.Address
            Do
                iFound = iFound + 1
                labelsArray(iFound) = f.Offset(1)
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
    GetValues = labelsArray
End Function
```

The data in the photos is not the actual data but rather it is just placeholders. A to K represent the category headers. Any value of number of special character denotes the data that is being collected under each category. As you may notice some categories do not have a value for the particular data set (row number) and hence I can't find a way for it to copy over the blank cells to the second sheet. Instead under the current code it simply ignores any blanks. That is why i wanted to perhaps offset where it pastes the data in the second sheet the data set's original row number.

**Update:**I have created a link to an example document.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/03p8n1u9y9nvbd5/Example.xlsm?dl=0